# Generic way of constructing smart pointed data types as well as normal data types

Tags: c++, smart-pointers, generic-programming

I would like to write a generic way for constructing a type `T` taking into account the case in which `T` is a smart pointer of the data I actually want to construct. Something like:

```
template < typename T, typename... Args >
auto
create( Args... args )
{
    return T{args...};
}

template < typename std::unique_ptr< typename T >, typename... Args >
auto
create( Args... args )
{
    return std::make_unique< T >( args... );
}

template < typename std::shared_ptr< typename T >, typename... Args >
auto
create( Args... args )
{
    return std::make_shared< T >( args... );
}
```

This way it will of course not compile. It is just to explain the rough idea. I need two more specific overloads, which are still generic enough to do the job.

Caller code should be able to do something like this:

```
const SomeType x1 = create<SomeType>(1, 2, 3);
const std::unique_ptr<SomeType> x2 = create<std::unique_ptr<SomeType>>(1, 2, 3);
```

Comment: How do you expect these to be called? You can't just call `create(args)` because C++ overload resolution doesn't take the return type into account. So you'd have to write something like `create<std::unique_ptr>(args)` at the very least. But at that point, you might as well just call your functions differently, like `create_unique`. And at _that_ point they lose their value because you might as well write `std::make_unique<T>` directly.

Comment: @Thomas I will add the expectations for the caller code in the question

Comment: @Jarod42 no the edit is wrong, the point of the question is that I have `SomeType` which might be pointer as well as it might not be pointer, but the caller will not know.

Comment: @nyarlathotep108: Feel free to fix the edit if inappropriate. but it seems to match your expectation (as you accept my answer)...

Comment: @Jarod42 your answer works without specifying in the user code if it is a smart pointer or not, I am just calling `create<T>` in every case and it works. Only current issue is if `T` is a smart pointer to a `POD` `struct` or any pointed aggregate

Comment: There is no problems with `const std::unique_ptr<int> x2 = create<std::unique_ptr<int>>(42);`... And indeed `const std::unique_ptr<int> x2 = create<int>(42);` is not supposed to compile. Do you expect it? if not can you provide problematic expression?

Comment: @Jarod42 yes, if you replace `int` with, for example, `std::array<int,2>` you should see the problem I am talking about

Comment: No problem [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2adc26afce8aab05). but you are indeed limited to argument that `std::make_unique` can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use overload that way, with some indirection:

```
template <typename T> struct Tag{};

template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto create_impl(Tag<T>, Args&&... args)
{
    return T{std::forward<Args>(args)...};
}

template < typename T, typename... Args >
auto create_impl(Tag<std::unique_ptr<T>>, Args&&... args)
{
    return std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
template < typename T, typename... Args >
auto create_impl(Tag<std::shared_ptr<T>>, Args&&... args)
{
    return std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template <typename T, typename... Args>
auto create(Args&&... args)
{
    return create_impl(Tag<T>{}, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```

Comment: The only use case I see this is not working is with a smart pointer POD...

Comment: If you have any solution also for the POD use case, feel free to edit the answer. For my question scope this works so the answer is accepted anyway.

Comment: I was not really planning to do it but if you have a solution also for that I am all hear

Comment: I try to understand your additional issue (without success).